# Notification cancel not working

Tags: android, firebase

Notification canceling works when i have one device. But when i add one more device with another id, it not cancel any of notifications. I dont understand what i am doing wrong.

Here is some code

```
private void cancelNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{
    int id = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("id"));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(id);
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url",remoteMessage.getData().get("url"));
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent , 0);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Notification notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.splash_launcher))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("text"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pintent)
            .build();

    int id = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("id"));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder);
}
```

Comment: **Off-topic** You deleted your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283360/not-clear-where-ffmpeg-gets-the-data-from) before I can post a comment. PS: I suspect your question was about MP4 structure itself (not like _"How to use FFmpeg commands correctly?"_)... PPS: Coment when you see this so I can delete it (since it's not for future readers).

Comment: There is broken file, i fixed mdat metadata, now i figure out that stco is wrong, maybe stts and ctts are too wrong. I see that ffmpeg fixing that, how i understand ffmpeg found 32 divider and file working with that, how ffmpeg done that this is for me question @VC.One

Comment: How is the `stco` box wrong? Is there a `co64` box? If the problem is a lot of zeroes then that's okay for fragmented MP4's moov box because later such info is inside each moof header. The Moof is the beginning of a new chunk. You can play any moof chunk as a separate file (but it must first reference the related moov for other metadata)

Comment: Do you use any (free) **hex editor** for checking a file bytes (eg: HxD for Windows)?

Comment: I see starts offsets are too big https://prnt.sc/SxrxEfnetZfl . My main task is to make an fmp4 chunked file with random access from mp4. I dont have problems with different files, in that file mdat length was 1, it is broking from beggining, but it is working video file. Ffmpeg somehow dealing with that and in example 20 in ctts converts into 640 and 40 to 1280, that this video works in from chunking. If i tryis to use data ctts and stts includes, it for me gives video artifacts @VC.One

Comment: I am getting confused... Your picture shows a file that starts FTYP (usually maximum length of 16 bytes), then you get MDAT then you get MOOV...  So is that showing the problematic file with a mdat length of 1? What is the real file size of it in file Explorer? This **1** number you got, is it another program telling you that it's only 1 byte (from bad header) or else do you really find only 1 byte in "mdat" section yourself (if you check file with a hex editor)? PS: _"starts offsets are too big"_ they are fine if the MDAT has enough real bytes. What is the resolution and FPS?

Comment: Also if I was trying to fix such a file and let's say it has only video (for a simple example)... (1) I would first get the SPS and PPS metadata (found in STSD atom) then I would go to MDAT atom and extract each frame by its size (because each sample (video frame) in MDAT starts with a 32-bit size integer). After extracting frames manually I would then join them up to make a raw H.264 file that can be re-muxed into a new MP4. (2) Can't explain CTTS and STTS problem without knowing the FPS and Duration. (3) It's possible that what you call corruption is the MP4 owner's idea of data protection.

Comment: @VC.One i think ill find a way to skip files like that and dont chunk them, i was starting with fixing mdat, then more and more problems were revealed. Thank you for your time

Comment: In my second comment I asked _"Is there a `co64` box?"_. You did not confirm but... If yes then it explains why your lengths are 1. It means after the atom name's 4 bytes,  there is 8 bytes for length then data itself. In such a file you read the lengths as 64-bits integers (not  the usual 32-bits, or 4 bytes). Without an existing `co64` entry in the file, then assume it must be corrupt / protected because length cannot be 1. A `co64` entry would let you know to work in 8-bytes per integer read, not as 4-bytes per integer reading. The `co64` text is on the right-hand side (in most hex editors)

Comment: @VC.One Your comment got me thinking, the right thoughts, I googled about 00 00 00 01 mdat length, and found the comment "It could be - the specification says that if 0, it stretches to EOF. If 1 it's 64 bit.". And indeed, the next 8 bytes from mdat were the size, which means that length 1 is equal to the 64-bit size representation. I'm thinking maybe create a new thread and mark this as an answer? I’ll also add that moov didn’t have co64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in the code you've shown. To cancel a notification you've previously sent you have to call the `cancel` function with the same id that you've used to call the `notify` function. If your code is not working the `RemoteMessage` you're giving to your `cancelNotification` function has a different id than the `RemoteMessage` you're giving to your `sendNotification` function.

Comment: Yes it was server side problem. I transfered notification id code into my foreach sender and changed it for looped code